# file_get_contents() doesn't match with url from file

Tags: php, bots, file-get-contents

I want to create a small bot. So i want to get html file from website to scan them. When I use file_get_contents("an_url_here") it works fine, but when I use url that I have record in a file, it makes an error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents("http://schema.org/LocalBusiness "): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/private/bot/bot3.php on line 15
```

I have my urls in a file .txt:

```
"https://www.chrismantcreation.fr"
"http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"
"http://schema.org/WebSite"
"http://www.mon-arbre-ma-genealogie.fr"
```

And this is my php code:

```
<?php
$lire_autres_pages = fopen('lien2.txt', 'r');
echo(file_get_contents("https://www.chrismantcreation.fr"); //THIS WORKS

while(!feof($lire_autres_pages)) {
  
  $page_suivante = fgets($lire_autres_pages);
  echo(file_get_contents($page_suivante)); // THIS DOESN'T WORK
}

fclose($lire_autres_pages);

?>
```

If someone has an idea because i don't understand why it happens.
I have the same issue if i use Curl.

Comment: remove space and line break from $page_suivante to get valid url

Comment: This might work: `echo (file_get_contents(trim($page_suivante)));`.

Comment: Thanks, trim($page_suivante) works but with string without quote:     trim("myurl") not good but trim(myurl) works. Tx you a lot, hours and hours lost yesterday!

Comment: trim() works cause i had a \n at the end lines i think. I didn't know trim(), I had tried preg_replace to clean my lines, but it doesn't do anythiing with invisibles characters

Answer (score 1):

So trim works: my url file (without quotes or double quotes):

```
https://www.chrismantcreation.fr
http://schema.org/LocalBusiness
http://schema.org/WebSite
http://www.mon-arbre-ma-genealogie.fr
```

My php code working:

```
<?php
$lire_autres_pages = fopen('lien2.txt', 'r');
echo(file_get_contents("https://www.chrismantcreation.fr"); //THIS WORKS

while(!feof($lire_autres_pages)) {
  
  $page_suivante = fgets($lire_autres_pages);
  echo(file_get_contents(trim($page_suivante))); // THIS WORKS !!!!!
}

fclose($lire_autres_pages);

?>
```

Thank for answering and have a good day!!